# Understanding a reimplementation of std::is_base_of

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I came across the following piece of code online. It's essentially meant to illustrate a way to implement `std::is_base_of` (perhaps not precisely).

I added numbered comments to associate lines with particular questions asked below:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

class Q {};

class Z : public Q {};

template<typename D, typename B>
class IsDerivedFromHelper
{
    class No { };
    class Yes { No no[3]; };

    static Yes Test( B* );  // (1) (2)
    static No Test( ... );  // (1) (3)
public:
    enum { Is = sizeof(Test(static_cast<D*>(0))) == sizeof(Yes) }; // (4)

};

template <class C, class P> 
bool IsDerivedFrom() {
    return IsDerivedFromHelper<C, P>::Is;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::cout << IsDerivedFrom<Z, Q>() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

There are quite a few things here that I didn't manage to figure out. Assistance will be appreciated.

1. It seems to me that `IsDerivedFromHelper` defines two static members *of the same name* (`Test`)? How is this possible?
2. The classes `No` and `Yes` both define no constructor, meaning they only have the default no-arguments constructor. If so, how are we able to pass `B*` (or `...`) to `Test()`?
3. I understand that `...` means variadic arguments. But - what does it mean in this situation?
4. Again, instantiating `Test` with an argument of type `D*` where the type of `Test` doesn't define a constructor. What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. It seems to me that IsDerivedFromHelper defines two static members of the same name (Test)? How is this possible?

Those member functions with the same name have different parameter lists. This is called function overloading.

> 2. The classes No and Yes both define no constructor, meaning they only have the default no-arguments constructor. If so, how are we able to pass B* (or ...) to Test()?

The return type of the function has no effect on what parameters can be passed into it.

> 3. I understand that ... means variadic arguments. But - what does it mean in this situation?

Variadic arguments.

> 4. Again, instantiating Test with an argument of type D* where the type of Test doesn't define a constructor.

A function is *called*, not *instantiated*. Functions do not have constructors.

> What is going on here?

A member function `Test` is called. The call may resolve to either overload depending on the template type arguments.

Comment: I see... the entire thing that confused me was the declaration-without-definition of the `Test` functions. I thought they were static members of type Yes and No respectively. Thanks for clearing that up. By the way - is there a more elegant way to check whether during compiletime the return type of `Test(something)` is `Yes` or `No`? Instead of relying on the `sizeof` hack as shown above.

Comment: @AvivCohn There are other ways. See the example implementation of is_same: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same